# Is there a way to cast float as a decimal without rounding and preserving its precision?

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting

So it appears that if you

```
CAST(field1 as decimal) field1
```

this will automatically add rounding.

The original is defined as:

field1  type:float  length:8    prec:53

I need to cast it to decimal, because I need my Entity Framework layer to generate this field as decimal (instead of double).

Is there a way to cast it as decimal, so that it preserves original precision, and doesn't round?

I would like to avoid having to declare the precision in the cast, because:

1. there are 100's of fields involved with varying precision, and;
2. if the underlying table changes in the future, it could cause unforeseen bugs to emerge, and;
3. makes the management more difficult.

Comment: IIRC, the default precision for DECIMAL is to three decimal places if you don't specify the precision.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
SELECT Cast( 2.555 as decimal(53,8))
```

This would return `2.55500000`.  Is that what you want?

**UPDATE:**

Apparently you can also use SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY to find the precision and scale of a value.  Example:

```
SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(Cast( 2.555 as decimal(8,7)),'Precision'),
SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(Cast( 2.555 as decimal(8,7)),'Scale')
```

returns `8|7`

You may be able to use this in your conversion process...

Comment: thanks, is it possible to omit declaring the precision ? yet preserving original?

Comment: Well it looks like even though you can assign precision and scale to variables you can't use those variables when declaring the precision and scale. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Try `SELECT CAST(field1 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) field1` and replace `10,2` with whatever precision you need.

Answer (score 2):

```
cast (field1 as decimal(53,8)
) field 1
```

The default is: decimal(18,0)

Comment: Thanks for telling what the default is, but where did you find that?