# Which rounding method SQL-Server uses to insert a number with several decimal places into a smaller column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, rounding

There are a lot of ways to cast a `decimal(8,6)` value to a `decimal(8,2)` (for example), but which one does SQL use when it is inserting a bigger decimal number into a smaller column?

This is a draft of the problem i have to solve:

```
create table #example (id1 int, id2 int, decValue decimal(8,2))
create table #compare (id2 int, id3 int, decValue decimal(8,6))

SELECT      E.id2, E.decValue, C.id2, SUM(C.decValue)
FROM        #example E 
FULL OUTTER JOIN 
            #compare C 
ON          C.id2 = E.id2
GROUP BY    E.id2, E.decValue, C.id2
HAVING      E.decValue <> SUM(C.decValue) OR 
            E.id2 is null OR
            C.id2 is null
```

The problem is that `SUM(C.decValue)` gets a number with more decimal places, so it won't match. I tried using `ROUND(SUM(C.decValue, 2))` and it still doesn't match most of the time.

Comment: Can you give an example of a `decimal(8,6)`  that doesn't end up with the same as `ROUND(C.decValue, 2)` when you insert it to a `decimal(8,2)`?

Comment: That's because you have it backwards. It would be SUM(ROUND(C.devValue, 2))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [casting as decimal and rounding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169520/casting-as-decimal-and-rounding)